# How to write a constructor for a type

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I can define a type like this:

```js
type Person = {
    givenName: string
    familyName: string
}
```

And I can define a constructor type for my type like this:

```js
type PersonConstructor = {
    new (givenName: string, familyName: string): Person
}
```

But I can't figure out the proper syntax for the constructor function implementation. The code below is invalid, and produces an error:

```js
const NamedPerson: PersonConstructor = (givenName: string, familyName: string) => {
    return { givenName, familyName }
}
```

```
Type '(givenName: string, familyName: string) => { givenName: string; familyName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PersonConstructor'.
    Type '(givenName: string, familyName: string) => { givenName: string; familyName: string; }' provides no match for the signature 'new (givenName: string, familyName: string): Person'.ts(2322)":
```

I can call the constructor, no problem, so the constructor type definition looks ok I think:

```js
const me = new NamedPerson('First', 'Last');
```

What is the proper syntax for an implementation of `PersonConstructor`?

Comment: You are not allowed to use arrow function for constructor. Arrow function does not have own `this`.  Further more , you are returning ` return { givenName, familyName }`, why do you need it as a constructor? IN order to use constructor you need to operate on `this`

Comment: The proper syntax is to use a `class` statement or expression, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N95ZVN).  If that's what you need I can write up an answer; if you're looking for something else, then please [edit] the question to clarify.  Let me know.

Comment: In my case I have hundreds of type aliases that were generated from a GraphQL schema. It would be really painful to create class definitions for each type alias and maintain them in sync. I am looking for a way to use the `new Xxx()` syntax to construct objects that are type compatible with the GraphQL schema.
I can also just create functions called `newXxx()` instead, I just think that `new Person()` is more comprehendible than `newPerson()`

Comment: This is just an example of the syntax, I don't actually have a `Person` type in my application where the constructor is pointless (as it is in this example). My actual code is more complicated and would obfuscate the issue, but the constructor does something useful.

Comment: But you can't `new` an arrow function, that's a `TypeError` at runtime.  The correct thing to do is use a `class`.  If you want to write a function that wraps an arrow function in a `class` to force the square peg into the round hole you can do so [as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbl69w), but it's not great (the TS compiler doesn't understand constructors that `return` something). Maybe you prefer `new Person` to `newPerson`, but you're fighting against TS and JS: people will be confused when `person instanceof Person` turns out to be *false*. How should we proceed here?

Comment: I just thought that if I can define a `PersonConstructor` type, then I should be able to write a function that conforms to this type, and constructs an object. Don't get hung up on the arrow function part, a regular function definition works just as well for my purpose.
If this is fighting with the language, then I can just stick with `newPerson(): Person`.

Comment: So how would you like to proceed with answering this question?  If I write an answer it will say something like: • the correct way to implement a constructor is with a `class` • if you want to use a function instead of a `class` you can force TS to allow it but there are plenty of caveats (arrow functions will explode at runtime unless you wrap them in a `class`, `instanceof` will be weird, etc) • if you want to use a function then you should probably just use a function signature and deal with writing `newPerson()` instead of `new Person()`. Would that work or am I missing something?

Comment: I posted an answer that works. If you want to post a better answer with more background information, I can mark your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to implement a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) is with a [`class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) declaration or expression:

```
const NamedPerson: PersonConstructor = class {
  constructor(public givenName: string, public familyName: string) { }
}

const person = new NamedPerson("John", "Doe");
console.log(person.familyName.toUpperCase()) // "DOE"
console.log(person instanceof NamedPerson); // true
```

In the above `class` expression I've used [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) to make the definition a little easier, but you don't need to use this.

---

If you want to use an arbitrary function instead, TypeScript doesn't want to make that easy for you.  ES5-style constructor functions work at runtime (where they assign properties to `this` instead of returning anything) but TypeScript doesn't want to add support for that and the advice is "use `class`es": see [microsoft/TypeScript#2310](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310).  Returning values from your constructor also works at runtime, but TypeScript doesn't currently let you mark class constructors as producing something other than its `this` type: see [microsoft/TypeScript#27594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27594) for the relevant feature request.  And TypeScript can't really tell the difference between [`function` expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) (which are `new`able) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (which explode at runtime if you `new` them, even if you never try to use `this` inside them), so even if the above two issues were addressed, you'd need to be careful that your function wasn't the wrong kind of function.

Right now, handling all of this requires some kind of wrapper function with [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress compiler warnings, and an implementation that makes arrow functions usable. Maybe like this:

```
function toConstructor<A extends any[], R extends object>(
  fn: (...args: A) => R): new (...args: A) => R {
  return class {
    constructor(...args: any) {
      return fn(...args);
    }
  } as any;
}
```

And then you'd use it like

```
const NamedPerson: PersonConstructor =
  toConstructor((givenName: string, familyName: string) => {
    return { givenName, familyName }
  });

const person = new NamedPerson("John", "Doe");
console.log(person.familyName.toUpperCase()) // "DOE"
console.log(person instanceof NamedPerson); // false
```

Oh, yeah, `person instanceof NamedPerson` is `false`, which is confusing. That's one of the drawbacks of constructors that return things instead of assigning to `this`; the prototype isn't set properly.   So even if TypeScript made it easy-ish to use arbitrary functions as class constructors, they'll lead to weird behavior.

---

If you want to minimize problems at runtime and with the compiler, you should use classes as classes and functions as functions and not mix them together.  If you've got a function then you'll have a better time just using it as a function without involving [the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) at all:

```
const namedPerson = (givenName: string, familyName: string): Person => {
  return { givenName, familyName }
}

const person = namedPerson("John", "Doe");
console.log(person.familyName.toUpperCase()) // "DOE"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgC4CeMyAChAE5QD2wSAvHoUUgOYCWAbhMABy4CAC4kUYjW7BO7IgDNw3DKWGRxk6bPYBffOzIUk1OowDCjLQFd4xejRZsOSYBADuACh78hIzVIynAA0SEpgKmr+EoGyAJTipgzAegZEoJCwCMjmGCBQUACiAB4wjgTySPBWxEjqEAAmSYyJtMmWwDZ2Dk7weQXOLlU1NLb2NJ4w1gBGGNzwXHwC9QHaIUhTs-NhyqorMWtxeEj6LvqV1Z21FGZMrG7udSJNbYyeAEQo9AAWwO+h7wAIvQIO84gBuC5WegYCAAOgw9E4k1ewDh4Ui9Th9gAqjAbuZ8hBPHEjgB6MlIIEAeUK7yhnRh8MRyJuySQMkkIGAiHoCiekBetwhSApJFGEDSJ3YGWgcEQSAA6jQQDBBkRLpIBY1msBWrcOl1xixKkR7IapGMHJ5vEs-BoDkFQhi9tEtEEjswAHzqoY0CDEaw0Ji4Ra+erO3ZRSDSoYnCFSxTWHnEbiMEj0C2jbo0AA8AEEkBBisQBA0oEhuaQANoAXVCACUiyWyxX6NMAFYQOxezymsJ6pCeOEjkA0ThQcT5z0+hsJVweIcjuFjidTmdIJsEOP+wPBqr9CvbuPDK7Z8bD0fjyeV4CkI7Hk9IXdBpgKYCXlfXhNP05DXSVhWVaQmcianlqbLpvci71EKyQfF8vz-FSwKgj+HCakyCJIiitzolGWK4vitCElAxKkqKlI0nSDIMLC2GsqiHJXNyvL8rBuoimKSgYGRUrnOkIhZAqABiyYLBULiarUspwVBQ4+MsbqxOsLrRmIjrxPq7Ler6RAvvuoaKfaECRhEroxn+RACRhNQbEx9zPLqCE-H8AKoWCIG2Yy9EsrhyT4eZ6nYvQeIEkSJLklRgK0vS-EGLoQA)

Answer (score 0):

After a few hints and much reading, the answer turns out to be:

```js
type Person = {
    givenName: string
    familyName: string
}

type PersonConstructor = {
    new (givenName: string, familyName: string): Person
}

const NamedPerson: PersonConstructor = class {
    givenName: string
    familyName: string
    constructor(givenName: string, familyName: string) {
        this.givenName = givenName
        this.familyName = familyName
    }
}

const me = new NamedPerson('First', 'Last');
```

However this requires me to write out all of the fields of `Person` multiple times, and it's not worth it considering I have over 100 type aliases and each one has a dozen or so fields.